# How to give multiple conditions in if elif conditions in python pandas script

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code like:

```
def sample_func(new_df):

   if ( new_df['name'] == 'Tom'):
      return "Yes"
   elif( new_df['name'].isin(['Harry', 'Jerry', 'Savi', 'Aavi'])):
      return "Common Name"
   else:
      return None
```

I am getting error as:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How to fix such errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code with `any` to get the result:-

```
def sample_func(new_df):
    if any( new_df['name'] == 'Tom'):
        return "Yes"
    elif any( new_df['name'].isin(['Harry', 'Jerry', 'Savi', 'Aavi'])):
        return "Common Name"
    else:
        return None
```

**Output**

```
Yes
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: I don't see the reason why you converted the elif to else if nested block

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal the first `else` is related to `for` loop AND this `else` contains `if-else`.

Comment: yes I know that but why not include it in simple if elif else block as in question @Rahulcharan

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Yes you can write code with `if elif else` also. I have modified my code, you can see it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
def sample_func(new_df):

    m1 = new_df['name'] == 'Tom'
    m2 = new_df['name'].isin(['Harry', 'Jerry', 'Savi', 'Aavi'])

    new_df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['Yes','Common Name'], default=None)
    return new_df
```

More information about your error is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas).

Comment: I am getting this error now, "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape", the scenario for which I am doing this is having different column name in variable m1 and m2.

Comment: @Dhiraj - What is `print (new_df.columns)` ?

Comment: @Dhiraj - because I guess there are duplicated column names, 2 or more  `name` columns

Comment: I can see the new column with the required values but can you explain me why i am getting the ValueError